# CGAffineTransform translation to negative X not working

Tags: swift, function, cgaffinetransform

I have two functions, one is translating view position to the *view.center.x + 200* — which works just as expected.

Second function is supposed to do the exact opposite, which is translating position to *view.center.x - 200*.

```
func like() {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
      self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.cardView.center.x + 200, y: 75)
   }
}

func dislike() {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
      self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.cardView.center.x - 200, y: 75)
   }
}
```

However second one is not working, it just moves X position a bit to the right and Y to specified position.

Comment: Code looks just fine. Please provide more details to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Kamran no it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation is already a relative amount based on the center. So do not involve the center in the equation.

```
func like() {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
      self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 200, y: 75)
   }
}

func dislike() {
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
      self.cardView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -200, y: 75)
   }
}
```